# Using wget and having websites working properly offline

Tags: wget

I am using wget to download websites, but I would like them to work properly offline. If the website is using jQuery from a website url for example, it will not work in offline mode.

Is there anyway to automate the process of getting things like jQuery stored locally? I don't want to go through the trouble if doing it manually every time.

Comment: I think that wget is not good tool for your task. You may try better tool - [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/). It is available in APT (`sudo apt-get install webhttrack`).

Answer (score 2):

Wget itself is capable of this:

```
wget -pk <URL>
```

`-p` causes wget to retrieve the page itself as well as any other resources the page uses such as images, scripts and stylesheets.  The result will be stored in a new directory, containing all the files downloaded.

`-k` causes wget to translate the URLs of these so they will work locally.

The above only retrieves one page, along with its resources.  If you want to try and retrieve a whole site, add `-r`:

```
wget -rpk <URL>
```

However, this comes with a warning:

- It may download hundreds, thousands, or many more pages if there are a lot of pages.  By default it uses a depth of 5, which is likely enough depth to retrieve a whole site unless the internal linking is a bit sparse.
- This may fill up your hard disk.
- It places undue load on the server you're downloading from.  Consider asking permission.

Comment: I did this, but the "script src" is still "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any links to external sites (sites on different hosts/domains) are not included.

These should still work perfectly fine when viewed locally though, except when you're viewing on a device with no internet access ie it is literally offline.

Comment: Problem is I need it for offline use. What I have to do now is store the jQuery link manually in my root, and it's tedious work changing the code when there's a lot of pages. I guess wget can't fix that then?